# How to get child element to display without position fixed from within parent with overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On one of my sites I have a menu which overflows so I added some jQuery to control the menu position, but my menu has dropdowns I still want the dropdowns to show outside the menu but as overflow hidden is applied without position fixed I cannot get it to show,

Is there no command in css that accounts for the need to sometimes make a child element visible again?

Is my only solution to use position fixed or rebuild the dropdown and menu so it expands the menu when an item is selected.

Comment: You need to show a link to your project or a jsfiddle to see the problem.

Comment: I have a menu which overflows.
This can hardly explain the scenario. You can add a jsfiddle so that we could check if we can avoid 

    overflow:hidden 

from there.

Comment: its a simple question you either know or you don't, it doesn't require a jsfiddle to just explain if there is any other way to get out of overflow:hidden; other than position:fixed; frankly the code is rather complicated and would take me like an hour to do which is only how long it will take for me just to write the js myself

Comment: @DominicNoble So you just expecting someone to provide the code because you can't be bothered to write it? Not going to encourage people to even attempt to answer your question. Think you may have misunderstood the purpose of SO.

Comment: thats not what i asked read the question, i asked if there was any other way, not asking for a complete solution. if you dont know its ok

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is a yes or no answer then:

No, you cannot have a child element that is outside of a parent with `overflow:hidden` be visible except with `position:fixed;`